# app compiler time with `ng serve --aot=true` takes more time than just `ng serve`

Tags: angular, angular8

I my angular app, i have no.of modules. when i change something with html or css it take time to re-compile. so i decided to start with `ng serve --aot=true` but I find it take more time to run the app compare to without any flag as `ng serve`. But what is wrong here or what is the purpose of `ng serve --aot=true` then?

any one help me to understand the `ng serve --aot=true` flag.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler

Comment: aot is for speeding up application running not application building

Comment: AOT is designed to make your application run fast *by spending longer compiling*. The JIT (Just In Time) compiler is designed for building and serving locally, during development, because it compiles faster. Use AOT when you build your app for deployment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular offers 2 ways to bind your application:

**Just-in-Time (JIT)**, which compiles your app in the browser at runtime. (when you run `ng serve`)

- Compiled in the browser
- Each files compiled separately
- No need to build after changing your code and before reloading the browser page
- **Suitable for local development**

**Ahead-of-Time (AOT)**, which compiles your app at build time. (when you run `ng serve --aot=true`)

- Compiled by the machine itself, via the command line (Faster)
- All code compiled together, inlining HTML/CSS in the scripts
- No need to deploy the compiler
- **Suitable for production builds**

> The ng build command with the --prod meta-flag (ng build --prod) compiles with AOT by default.
>
> The Angular Ahead-of-Time (AOT) compiler converts your Angular HTML and TypeScript code into efficient JavaScript code during the build phase before the browser downloads and runs that code. Compiling your application during the build process provides a faster rendering in the browser.

As **JIT** compiles your app at runtime, it can optimize the compilation and only build necessary code. So in development mode, it's common to use JIT to save the time of a full build. The compilation time will be faster using JIT.

**AOT** optimizes the running speed but the compilation time is longer, thats why it's common to use it in production. AOT will also optimize the size of your application as all files will be compiled before running it.